# Mips: Computing the sum of two inputs

Tags: assembly, mips

It seems very simple but I think my program won't compile because I'm overwriting the $v0 register? Thanks in advance

UPDATE:nevermind got it, my order was wrong when I made the syscall for printing the sum...
fixed in case anyone needs reference.

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\n\n Enter the first integer please:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer please:"
result: .asciiz "The result is:"

.text

main:

    #t0-to hold first integer
    #t1-to hold second integer
    #t2- used to hold the sum of t$1 and t$2

        #first number

    li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
        la $a0, prompt1  #address of string to print
        syscall

        li $v0, 5 #syscall to read an integer
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0  #move the number to read into $t0

    #second number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall

    li $v0,5        
        syscall
    move $t1,$v0

        add $t2, $t1, $t0 #compute the sum

    #print out sum of $t2
    li $v0, 4       # load syscall print int into $v0
    move $a0, $t2   #move the number to print into $a0
    li, $v0,1
    la, $a0, result
    syscall


Done:

    li $v0, 10    #syscall to exit
        syscall
```

Comment: Flagged to close as this was the result of a simple typographical error; it's extremely unlikely that anyone finding this page will be satisfied with the same solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\n\n Enter the first integer please:"
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the second integer please:"
result: .asciiz "The result is:"

              .text
main:
    #t0-to hold first integer
    #t1-to hold second integer
    #t2- used to hold the sum of t$1 and t$2
        #first number
        li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
        la $a0, prompt1  #address of string to print
        syscall
#
        li $v0, 5 #syscall to read an integer
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0  #move the number to read into $t0
    #second number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall
#
    li $v0,5        
    syscall
    move $t1,$v0
#
    #print out sum of $t2
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result
    syscall
#
    add $a0, $t1, $t0 #compute the sum
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
#
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not very useful. It would be better if you could provide some explanation as to how this helps to solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you messed up in this section:

`#print out sum of $t2
    li $v0, 4       # load syscall print int into $v0
    move $a0, $t2   #move the number to print into $a0
    li, $v0,1
    la, $a0, result
    syscall`

Lets do it line by line:
`li $v0, 4  #You are ready to indicate that you want to print string`
`la $a0, result #you have loaded the address of string now`
`syscall # Now you will see: "The result is:`

Now lets print the number
`li $v0, 1`
`move $a0, $t2`
`syscall`

Footnote: Everytime you indicate you will use syscall, you should complete that command first. 
for example, if you want to print something, you must complete syscall for that set and then move on to print integer.

example:
Lets say we want to print something like this,.
Number : 1

MIPS code would be:
`.data
     prompt: .asciiz "Number : " 
.text
main:
   #Now lets read a number 
   li $v0, 5
   syscall # -> note syscall is done for each instruction
   #Lets complete printing first
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, prompt
   syscall`

#We have the number in $t0 right now 
   #if we do
   `li $v0, 1
   la $a0, prompt
   syscall`
   #ask question and answer yourself. what will be printed. 
   #the numbe we had entered or adress of prompt
   #what do you need to modify here?

Answer (score 0):

```
.text
main:
    #print the msg1
    li $v0 4
    la $a0 msg1
    syscall 

    #read the num 1
    li $v0 5
    syscall

    sw $v0 a1

    #print the msg2
    li $v0 4
    la $a0 msg2
    syscall 

    #read the Num 2
    li $v0 5
    syscall

    sw $v0 a2

    #print the msg3
    li $v0 4
    la $a0 msg3
    syscall 

    lw $t0 a1
    lw $t1 a2


    li $v0 1
    add $a0 $t0 $t1
    syscall  
.data
    msg1: .asciiz "Enter the first number :"
    msg2: .asciiz "Enter the second number :"
    a1 : .word 0
    a2 : .word 0
    msg3: .asciiz  "The sum is = "
```

Comment: A code only posting to a solved question isn't helpful. If you have something important to add that the community can benefit from, please include some explanatory comments.